# flutter how to get marker id when marker click?

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter. I want to get the clicked marker id when a marker is clicked on Google Maps. Or I would like to know if I clicked a marker or a map area. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

First, you will create some variables,

one that will be the value of the `markerId: MarkerId(markerValue1)`:

```
String markerValue1 = 'Your Marker Id';
```

one that will store the latest `markerId` value:

```
String latestMarkerValue;
```

Then you will add in your Marker widget the`onTap:` method:

```
onTap: (){
latestMarkerValue=markerValue1;
}
```

You will do this for every marker.
If you want to have all the clicked markers' ides then you will change the value of the `latestMarkerValue`

```
latestMarkerValue= latestMarkerValue==null?latestMarkerValue= 'markerValue1':latestMarkerValue='$latestMarkerValue $markerValuen'
```